Signaling to Shabbat goy
Shabbat elevator is broken. Assume Shabbat goy is accepted. What are permissible strategies to signal to the building lobby when going down from upper floors? Medical necessity thank you

If this is a medical necessity, you must contact a Rabbi ASAP (and definitely not Mi Yodeya)

If medical necessity, call him on his cell phone
